# C language beginner

Tags: c

I'm learning C language following Youtube video and I've got couple of questions.

I typed these below in Xcode

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()  // 1. why do we have to use this line?
{
  char food[] = "tuna";

  printf("the best food is %s",food);
  strcpy(food,"bacon");  // error here
  return 0;
}
```

2. When I typed these all, the error come out saying " implicity declaring library function 'strcpy' with type '`char*(char*,const char*)`'"

I have no idea what this mean and why it happened? Sorry to bother with question guys but I need your help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Place take care of formatting your post and mark code.

Comment: Why, just why, youtube? Use a good book, there's still no substitute to K&R for learing, IMHO.

Comment: Don't learn C programming from Youtube and you'll probably have far less questions. The things you ask are explained in any half-decent beginner-level C programming book.

Comment: BTW, you didn't mention _which_ youtube video you are talking about.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, we need the link for the video so we can go and downvote it!!!!

Comment: Please don't ask about something shown in obscure youtube videos. They are good for cat-contents, but not learning C. Get a good **and modern** C book (K&R is outdated, get one for standard C, i.e. C11, at least C99). The code already shows bad practice and has (apparently) errors and flaws.

Comment: Note that the `strcpy()` invokes undefined behaviour by writing outside the bounds of the array, but the changed value isn't used, which makes the change pointless.

Comment: The space allocated by `char * food[]` (5 bytes) is not capable to contain "bacon"! ... In c all "string" are terminated by a byte 0. Then "tuna", which initializes food is 5 byte, while "bacon" is 6 byte.

Comment: thanks guyS!  so you guys recommend to study it by book right? anyway here's a linkhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7F-Q2oVBYKk

Answer (score 2):

C is a super great language to learn but because of how low level it is in comparison to python, javascript, etc. There are many manual tasks you need to do including memory management.

But before we get into that, your initial problem is not including the `string.h` header. Once you include that header, you'll actually get Segmentation Fault.

Below is the explanation on why you'll get the Segmentation Fault.

So when you defined:
`char food[] = "tuna"`

C created char array with 5 bytes. Why 5? because all strings end with a NULL byte (`'\0'`).

So your string in memory looks like `"tuna\0"`.

Side note:

The importance of the NULL byte is to signify the end of a string. This is super important when you are using a function like `printf`. Because when printing a string, `printf` will look for the NULL byte to stop printing.

So this char array has the max size of 5 bytes, 1 being a null byte, so just 4 bytes (chars) of writeable memory.

Then you try to copy the word "bacon" into your 5 byte array.

So strcpy tries to copy the b, then the c, then the o, then the n, then when it tries to terminate the string with a NULL byte, it will seg fault because you're trying to access a byte of memory you don't have access to.

So in order to fix your issue, you could try to `strcpy` a string that is the same length or shorter than your original string. Or you can look into something like `strdup` and use pointers.

That code will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char *food = "tuna";

  printf("the best food is %s\n",food);

  food = strdup("bacon");

  printf("the best food is %s\n",food);

  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The best! you are not only good at computer but also sharing it to others!! Thanks heaps

Comment: He was not getting segmentation fault, he was getting error as `implicity declaring library function 'strcpy' with type `'char*(char*,const char*)``, which is because he forgot to include `string.h` once this file is include then he will get error due to what you have mentioned

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu you are super correct! I overlooked that issue. Thanks for commenting on that. Will edit my answer to reflect your addition :)

Answer (score 0):

1. We have to use `main()`,this is the function through which execution of C program starts.
2. For using `strcpy()`(A predefined function) you need to declare it first. and its declaration is present in `string.h` so just `#include<string.h>`
   This will resolve your problem.`implicit declaring library function 'strcpy' with type`'char*(char*,const char*)``

There is one more problem when you declare

`char food[]="tuna";`

you get only 5 bytes allocated for you,four for character and one more for NULL.  When you will try putting `bacon`in it (using `strcpy()`),which is 6 bytes long. It will cause compiler to create segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you as exercise to explain me the behavior of this code. You have to understand how "strings" are managed by the C language into the memory.

The code I post below is not right, contains a violation of the space allocated for the variable `food`. In this case this code doesn't generate a Segmentation Fault, but It might generate such a error!

If you compile the code below with `gcc -Wall --pedantic -std=c99 prgname.c`
, the compiler doesn't signal warnings nor error, but the code is NOT RIGHT.

PAY ATTENTION! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()  // 1. why do we have to use this line?
{           //  --- 'cause is a standard!!! :)
  char food[] = "tuna";
  char b[]="prova";

  printf("the best food is %s - %s - food-size %u\n",food,b,(unsigned int)sizeof(food));
  strcpy(food,"fried or roasted bacon");  // error here
  printf("the best food is %s - %s - food-size %u\n",food,b,(unsigned int)sizeof(food));

return 0;
}
```